# Javascript: Map in for loop always return last item

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to modify an array of objects and I use a map inside a for loop. My implementation always seem to return the last item in the map.

Code:

```
let testArray = [
    {
        body: 'test sentence',
        uid: "a"
    },
    {
        body: 'Another test sentence',
        uid: "b"
    }
]

var allItems = []
for (var item of testArray) {
    let splittedBody = item.body.split(' ')

    let splittedArray = splittedBody.map((word, i) => {
        item.body = word
        item.objectID = `${item.uid}:${i}`
        return item
    })
    allItems.push(splittedArray)
}

allItems = Array.prototype.concat(...allItems)
console.log(allItems)
```

The above code prints the following:

```
[ { body: 'sentence', uid: 'a', objectID: 'a:1' },
  { body: 'sentence', uid: 'a', objectID: 'a:1' },
  { body: 'sentence', uid: 'b', objectID: 'b:2' },
  { body: 'sentence', uid: 'b', objectID: 'b:2' },
  { body: 'sentence', uid: 'b', objectID: 'b:2' } ]
```

What I want is:

```
[ { body: 'test', uid: 'a', objectID: 'a:0' },
  { body: 'sentence', uid: 'a', objectID: 'a:1' },
  { body: 'Another', uid: 'b', objectID: 'b:0' },
  { body: 'test', uid: 'b', objectID: 'b:1' },
  { body: 'sentence', uid: 'b', objectID: 'b:2' } ]
```

**EDIT:**
Ideally, I would not like to construct another item in my map function because each object in the `testArray` may have attributes that do not exist in other object. Constructing another item in the map function would mean that I have to check for `undefined` in those attributes and this is very prone to errors.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I don't think you want to do `item.body = word`, that will overwrite the original sentence.

Comment: Create a `var item = {}` inside the `map`

Comment: You don't want to set `item` in your inner loop, which is your outer loop's iteration variable. Just build a new object in your map function: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/x42qjwvc/

Comment: I updated my answer to accomplish what you want in your `edit` section. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here come from the shadowing that you do with `item`:

```js
let testArray = [{
    body: 'test sentence',
    uid: "a"
  },
  {
    body: 'Another test sentence',
    uid: "b"
  }
]

var allItems = []
for (var item of testArray) {
  let splittedBody = item.body.split(' ')

  let splittedArray = splittedBody.map((word, i) => {

    // Create a clone of item -> don't use item
    var itemClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)); 
    
    itemClone.body = word
    itemClone.objectID = `${item.uid}:${i}`
    return itemClone       // <-- return the modified clone
  })
  allItems.push(splittedArray)
}

allItems = Array.prototype.concat(...allItems)
console.log(allItems)
```

`item` was declared in the for loop:

```js
for (var item of testArray) {
```

But then you actually modified the body and the objectID from it:

```js
    let splittedArray = splittedBody.map((word, i) => {
        item.body = word
        item.objectID = `${item.uid}:${i}`
```

Comment: Ideally, I do not want to construct a new item to append to `allItems` because each object in the json can have differing attributes. Each object has up to 10 attributes and constructing a new item means that I have to check for `undefined` in all the differing attributes. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: @Koh Yes you can do that using a clone of the initial `item`. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) for more details. I updated my example.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `item.body`, it mutates the original object. And you need more objects than the length of the `testArray` since you create new objects by splitting.

**Update**:

Since you want existing properties of `item` to remain, you can use [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as following:

```js
let testArray = [{
    body: "test sentence",
    uid: "a",
    foo: 'foo'
  },
  {
    body: "Another test sentence",
    uid: "b",
    bar: 'bar'
  }
];

var allItems = []
for (var item of testArray) {
  allItems.push(
    item.body.split(' ').map((word, i) => ({
        ...item,
//    ^^^^^^^ Here you can use spread operator to merge newly created object with the item

        body: word,
        objectID: `${item.uid}:${i}`
      })
    )
  )
}

allItems = Array.prototype.concat(...allItems)
console.log(allItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this simple.

```
let testArray = [
{
    body: 'test sentence',
    uid: "a"
},
{
    body: 'Another test sentence',
    uid: "b"
}
]
var allItems = [];
    for (var item of testArray) {
      let splittedBody = item.body.split(' ')
      splittedBody.map((word, i) => {
        let item1: any = {};
        item1.body = word;
        item1.uid = item.uid;
        item1.objectID = `${item.uid}:${i}`;
        allItems.push(item1);
      });
    }
    allItems = Array.prototype.concat(...allItems);
    console.log(allItems);
```